# Is It Proper To Put Code In Slides For Technical Presentation for Interview?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, technology, presentations

Im doing a technical presentation for a job interview and the topic is the following:

Minimizing Real-Time Data Stream Latency: Node.js and Asynchronous Operations

I've done some very thorough research on the topic and I want to add some code blocks to a few slides to visually show how to do Asynch Programming in Node.js as well as to visually show pros and cons.

Is it appropriate to add code blocks to some slides? The presentation is for 30-40 minutes. If it is appropriate, how many slides is to much. I want to keep it to about 10-12 slides.

Thanks.

Comment: This was [cross-posted in Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40832/is-it-appropriate-to-put-code-in-slides-for-a-technical-presentation)... please don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding something like that really depends on the audience you're speaking to.  I'd imagine that, more or less, since you're talking to people that know Javascript, are familiar with Node, and would know what an asynchronous operation is, then putting code in the slides would be OK.

That said, **there is a limit to how much code you should put in a presentation.** If you can, keep it context-specific, and make your snippets small.

Consider the audience once more.  The likelihood is that they can't thoroughly inspect or ask questions about code that appears on screen for a short amount of time. They might prefer to look at it in their own time, or want a copy of it to preview before/during/after the presentation itself.   Ultimately, you don't want to give people in a presentation lots of lines of code to look at.

If it's at all possible/permissible, throw it up on a code hosting repository (GitHub, Bitbucket, etc), and then use that as the key reference.  You could say, "This is the repository for the full code which I have written, and if you want to take a look at the whole thing, it's all over there."

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The majority of my audience are PhD in engineering and they know what JavaScript and Node.js is.  They know that I don't know too much of it as they wanted me to do a presentation on something I didn't know to much of to show them that I can learn.  With that being said, the code snippets are very small...there is one that is bigger to show the "Pyramid of Doom".  I just want to show the difference between Single CB Function, Event Emitters, difference in error catching, and difference in sync and async code.  Any more suggestions for me?

Comment: Ph. D in engineering doesn't really mean (to me at first blush) that they know JavaScript.  Not much else that I can add to what I've already said, though; it's important for you to consider the audience when you're doing this presentation.

Comment: And make sure nothing in your code snippet is proprietary.